# is the film on the story of Islam "The Message" (1976) accurate and permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, islamic-basis, bidah, halal-certification

I believe there has only been one film "[The Message](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075143/)" on the birth of Islam and the Prophet Muhammad (saws) and the director used the camera as the Prophet to avoid showing him with an actor. Has there ever been any opposition to the film? At the start it says that Al Azhar's scholars have certified it.

Comment: AFAIK it has not been defused in many Arabic states, for the reason that it might have been showing some of the ten sahaba who where promised paradise.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by accurate. You can't put 20-30 years in 2-3h and expect that no essential part of the history has been left out.